# Why is padStart not working for data from context.getImageData array?

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata

I am having trouble trying to get the hex value of a pixel. I found some code from an [example](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-extract-the-colour-of-a-pixel-using-javascript-and-html-5-f3661f54473) and I began debugging only to find that `toString(16)` didn't always output the correct number and `padStart(2, "0")` had absolutely no affect. I tried to make my own list and it worked fine, I tried an individual number and it worked fine, however when I use data from `context.getImageData()` it just doesn't produce the expected result at all.

I have made a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pajidaz/edit?js,output) that further shows the issue. Just upload an image, scroll down, and look at the output.

Comment: Please next time, the code goes in the question itself.